# How to detect whether a type is a lambda expression at compile time?

Tags: c++, lambda, template-meta-programming

Suppose I have a type `my_struct` enclosing a member variable, `f`, which is a function. It's possible for `f` to be a c++11 lambda function.

Since it is illegal to assign to lambda objects, I'd like to implement `my_struct`'s assignment operator in such a way that when `f` is a lambda, it is not assigned.

Is it possible to build a type trait `is_lambda` which can inspect a type for lambda-ness?

In code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Function> struct is_lambda
{
  // what goes here?
};

template<typename Function> struct my_struct
{
  Function f;

  my_struct &do_assign(const my_struct &other, std::true_type)
  {
    // don't assign to f
    return *this;
  }

  my_struct &do_assign(const my_struct &other, std::false_type)
  {
    // do assign to f
    f = other.f;
    return *this;
  }

  my_struct &operator=(const my_struct &other)
  {
    return do_assign(other, typename is_lambda<Function>::type());
  }
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Impossible without compiler support, as the type of a lambda is just a normal, non-union class type.

`§5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda] p3`

> The type of the *lambda-expression* (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed nonunion class type [...]

Answer (score 6):

Presumably you don't want to assign non-assignable non-lambda functions either, so you could use `std::is_assignable`.

Comment: This seems to work in Visual C++ 2015, maybe in earlier versions as well.  Using simply: `std::is_assignable<decltype(lam). decltype(lam)>::value`.  I used this method to ensure a lambda wasn't derived from when using _EBO_.

Comment: @MatthewHolder That sort of misses the point of my answer though, which is that you shouldn't try to give lambdas special treatment. There's nothing inherently wrong with deriving from a lambda. It has some aspects that may make it tricky, but those same aspects can apply to non-lambda classes. The fact that they aren't assignable isn't one of them, so in your case, I think that isn't the aspect that should be checked.

Comment: Understandable, but a situation that required me to detect a lambda was when passing a FunctionObject to a class template type argument that will be used as the base class of the class template for Empty Base Optimization. Since you cannot inherit a lambda type in certain situations or on certain compilers.  As this situation improves... that will no longer be an issue.

Comment: @MatthewHolder That's still missing the point. You should be detecting whether you can use the type as a base class. Non-class-types cannot be derived from either. Final classes cannot be derived from either. In situations where the compiler doesn't allow deriving from lambdas, detecting whether you can derive from the type should already cover lambdas just as well as all other scenarios. In situations where the compiler does allow deriving from lambdas, detecting whether you can derive from the type prevents false negatives.